# How to route the Python script output to a file

Tags: python, file, output, routes

I have a following script in python.
for i in range(10000):
    print i

Above piece of python code prints the value of i from 0 to 9999 on the console.

Now I would like to route the output of the script directly to an external file.
On linux, I can get it done using the following command

$ python python_script.py > python_out.txt

**What is the equivalent command on windows 7, IDLE Python Shell and under PyLab ?**

Also, Above script prints numbers from 0 to 9999. I would like to take a snapshot of the output, 
i.e. I want to route the first 85 records / numbers to out1.txt    OR
     I want to route the numbers that are divisible by 5 to out2.txt
**without changing the actual script.**

Also provide me the Python documentation to find out more.

Comment: does [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) help?

Comment: what do you mean by **without changing the actual script** ? If you want to write to different files based on some conditions then you've to modify the script.

Answer (score 3):

```
file1, file2 = "out1.txt", "out2.txt"
with open(file1,'w') as f1,open(file2,"w") as f2:
    for i in range(10000):
        if i < 85:
            f1.write("{0}\n".format(i))  # write to out1.txt
        if i%5==0:
            f2.write("{0}\n".format(i))  #write to out2.txt
        print i                 #write to stdout or python_out.txt in your case
```

and run this program as:

```
$python python_script.py > python_out.txt
```

Comment: Hi Ashwini, I don't like to change the Python script.  Python script is fine.   Your python code works only with the command line.  It can't run properly by directly invoking the python script as it expects 2 file names as args.   This is not what I'm expected.   More over the command will not work on Windowsn

Comment: @Kranti These commands work fine in windows,linux or mac, I've changed the code you can simply specify the filenames inside the code. And how do you expect a script to behave in a different way without changing the script?

Comment: Ashwini, I tried many ways to run the command but of no luck.  I have added you on facebook.  Can you come online and help me ?

Comment: @Kranti which command? `python_script.py > python_out.txt` will only write to `python_out.txt`. You can't expect a script like `for i in range(10000): print i`  to somehow magically write output to 3 different file that too with conditions. Sorry, no questions over fb or mail.

Comment: Yes, I opened cmd prompt and enter Python shell.  On getting >>> I entered the command C:\Users\Kranti\Desktop\Python\python_script.py    I'm getting syntax error for this.

Comment: @Kranti to run a python script simply open cmd, type : `C:\Users\Kranti\Desktop\Python\python_script.py` and hit enter.

Comment: I got syntax error pointing to colon in the command C:\Users\Kranti\Desktop\Python\python_script.py

Comment: @Kranti Don't enter the python shell, in cmd type: `python C:\Users\Kranti\Desktop\Python\python_script.py`. If you want to run a python script from shell or a python program then have a look a [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: this helps, I'm able to route the output to a file, finally.  Now, let me know more formats of such commands.

Comment: @Kranti without modifying the script this is the only way to redirect the output, otherwise you've to modify your script and add some file handling stuff to it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit ugly code, but you won't have to change your script.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, filename, predicate=(lambda ln, v:True)):
        self.filename = filename
        self.lines = 0
    def write(self, text):
        if predicate(self.lines, text):
            with open(self.filename, 'a') as f:
                f.write(text)
        self.lines += text.count('\n')
```

Usage:

```
import sys

def predicate(linenumber, text):
    if text.isdigit():
        if int(text) % 5:
            return False
    return True

sys.stdout = A('out1.txt', predicate)

for i in range(10000):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a file and write in it, something like this.

```
f = open('write_to_this_file.txt', 'w')
for i in xrange(10000):
    f.write(i + "\n")
```

Here is more info http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: No, This is straight forward answer. But I would like to know the alternate way of routing the program output to a file using python commands